# Convert pixels to world space units

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm planning to make my sprite dimension to be 1.5 inches to all devices. My problem now is convert the pixels to world space units so that I can scale my sprite correctly.

float pixelLength = Screen.dpi * 1.5f; // 1.5 inches

// code to convert pixelLength to world space units

Answer (score 0):

```
float pixelLength = Screen.dpi * 1.5f;

// Using your sprite's pixel per unit...
float worldLength = pixelLength / spriteRenderer.sprite.pixelsPerUnit;
```

Alternatively, instead of scaling your sprites, you can change the Camera's `OrthographicSize`. Changing `OrthographicSize` works better if all of your sprites' PixelPerUnit are roughly the same, and you are scaling everything.

Comment: not working. for example phone 1 screen dpi is 96 the other is 420 and their PPU is 100. So the screen dpi with 96 scale is . 48 and the other one is 2.1